# Таймер на PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Подскажите как при минимальном if-else сделать таймер обратного отсчёта. Пример: 04:11:58, без Js, то есть чтобы часы обновлялись при перезагрузке страницы. Время берется из разности time() и значения из базы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$r=mysql_query("select...");
list($r)=mysql_fetch_array($r);
$r=$r-time();
if($r>0)
{
  $s=$r%60;$r=(int)($r/60);
  $m=$r%60;$h=(int)($r/60);
  echo ($h<10?'0':'')."$h:".($m<10?'0':'')."$m:".($s<10?'0':'')."$s";
}
else
{
  //время пришло
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В каком формате хранится в базе?
Если timestamp иди datetime, то не понятно что вы "ифить" хотите.

Comment: Нет, там храниться время отправленное функцией time()

Comment: Если Вам до завтра не ответят, то накидаю. Просто я уже ушел спать.

Answer (score -1):

```
$start_time = time();

$timer_seconds = 60; // 
if(time() - $start_time+60 > 0) {
   // если таймер сработал
}
```